# Decryp sd card on samsung s9

Tags: external-sd

I've encrypted my sd csrd on my old phone. This has since broken and wont turn on. I upgraded to a samsung s9 and put my sd card in. It wont let me decrypt the sd cre through any password or pin an tells me to decrypt it on my old phone first before being able to use it on my new phone. Help please

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the encryption is tied to the phone as well as the password.

Have you tried connecting the device to a computer to see if it will come up enough to let you transfer files or is it hard bricked?